# How to update scripts from package json file using node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio-code

How to update scripts from package.json by node js. I want to update `"ng-pk":"npm install --save datemodule daysmodule"` i want to add one more module "timemodule" using nodejs in vs code.

Example:-

package.json:

```
{
    "name": "test app",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "scripts": {
        "start": "node script1.js",
        "ng-pk":"npm install --save datemodule daysmodule" 
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you not just putting the modules directly into the dependancies section of package.json?

Comment: Which version of npm are you using? npm since version 5 makes using `--save` obsolete, as it is done per default. Why are you generating scripts for `npm install ${package}` tasks? Each `npm install {package}` could be run once and then it will persist in both you package.json and package-lock.json. So I am having trouble understanding what you want to achieve. As to me, it appears you should run only `npm install timemodule`.

Comment: @k0pernikus: So we can not update "ng-pk" module by programaticaly rite?

Comment: You can change the `ng-pk` script to whatever you want. You can have it as `npm install --save datemodule daysmodule timemodule`. The question is, why do you want it inside this script to begin with?

Comment: Because after i installed module i want to update the module name in ng-pk.child = exec("npm install --save" + module_ins,
{
  cwd: '/path_to_angular_project'
},
function (error, stdout, stderr) {

Comment: @k0pernikus : Is it possible or not ?